# Invite user to promotion after "liking" a post

Tags: facebook, policy

Our app would send users who liked a post a customized invitation to join a FB promotion. The user can then decide if he wants to participate or not by following the link to the promotion. As long as users are not incentivised to LIKE the post and can access the promotion without LIKING the post we are compliant with the FB platform policy below, correct?

1.You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.

Many thanks in advance!
Florian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is violation of the TOS but there is some super simple javascript that will make this work

```
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    alert('You just liked the page!'); //Invite the user to promotion
  });
```

EDIT: Yes, [incentivising likes on facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=222089304469115#Is-incentivizing-Liking-an-app-allowed?) is ok in this circumstance.

Comment: Thanks! While this is helpful I need surety about being FB compliant.

Comment: After re-reading your post I think that you are correct in that assumption. As long as members can access the promotion via another (possibly obnoxious :P) route you are in the clear.

Comment: Thanks again! How would I go about to get final confirmation on policy questions directly from Facebook?